# Proving that a face diagonal of a cube is orthogonal to a body diagonal

Tags: geometry, orthogonality

If we consider the following cube, I have found in an exercise:

> Prove that $(FH)$ and $(AG)$ are orthogonal.
>
> [image: 1]

But I don't think that's even true.

Comment: It's true, but thinking one thing or another won't get us far. Try to actually prove it.

Comment: well because, $(AG)$ is not orthogonal on the plane $(FHG)$ @5xum

Comment: So what? True, the vector FH lies in that plane, but it also lies in a thousand or more of other planes. Some of them are orthogonal to AG, some aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec{i}:=\overrightarrow{BC},\,\vec{j}:=\overrightarrow{BA},\,\vec{k}:=\overrightarrow{BF}$ so $\overrightarrow{FH}=\vec{i}+\vec{j},\,\overrightarrow{AG}=\vec{i}-\vec{j}+\vec{k}$ are orthogonal. But we don't need a specific coordinate system to note $\overrightarrow{FH}$ is orthogonal to $\overrightarrow{AG}$, because $\overrightarrow{FH}$ is orthogonal to $\overrightarrow{AC}$, which is $\overrightarrow{AG}$'s projection onto a plane containing $\overrightarrow{FH}$ normal to $\overrightarrow{CG}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I$ be the midpoint of $HD$ and $J$ be the one of $BF$ and $a$ the length of the cube's edge.  Then $IJ$ is parallel to $FH$ and meets $AG$ in $M$.  Consider the triangle $GMI$.  Now the square of $GI$ is $\frac54a^2$, the square of $MI$ is $a^2/2$ and the square of $MG$ is $\frac34a^2$, all by Pythagoras. Observe that the the squares of $MG$ and $MG$ sum up to the square of $GI$. By Pythagoras again, $\angle GMI$ is $\pi/2$.